# What is ComposeViewAdapter used for in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a simple composable function in *com.example.Example.kt*:

```kotlin
@Preview
@Composable fun ExampleComposable() {
    Text("Hello")
}
```

I tried to use *ComposeViewAdapter* like below:

```xml
<androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:composableName="com.example.ExampleKt" />
```

Android Studio does not show any preview of the composable in the design pane.

Also, how is *ComposeViewAdapter* different from *androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView*?

Answer (score 3):

`Example.kt` file can have many composables, you need to specify the composable name:

```xml
<androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:composableName="com.example.ExampleKt.ExampleComposable" />
```